# curl and file_get_content not work properly

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents, web-crawler

I want to write a crawler program to extract phone numbers from  another site.I need to take it from nearly `2000 links`.Some times it works.I have done this using `curl and file_get_contents` .But some times I can't get contents from the site.Sometimes it shows `520 error occurs`.Is there any other way to do this? Any one Please help me...My code is

```
    $original_file = @file_get_contents($url);

   OR

   $ch = curl_init();

    // set url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);


    //return the transfer as a string
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // $output contains the output string
     $original_file = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: It can be server side http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error

Comment: The status code 520 is non-standard and undocumented. This is a server side problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

Comment: i'm sure that Navaneetha Nair meant 502 Bad Gateway response, which could mean that the site is throttling/blocking and you should slow down your requests